# GWT Loggers: Different Levels to Different Handlers

Tags: java, gwt, logging, gwt-log4j

I'm trying to configure my first GWT Logger and so far have log messages printing to my JS console (Firebug for FF):

```
<!-- Configure logging. -->
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="FINEST"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.firebugHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="DISABLED" />
```

Ultimately, I'd like non-`SEVERE` messages to go to the `consoleHandler`, and `SEVERE` messages to go to the `simpleRemoteHandler`.

How can I accomplish this? How can I get certain log levels to go to 1 handler, and `SEVERE` messages to go to another? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way according with the gwt [logging documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Loggers_Handlers_and_the_Root_Logger) is:

`GWT logging comes with a set of Handlers already defined and (by default) attached to the Root Logger. You can disable these handlers in the .gwt.xml file as discussed above, extend them, attach them to other loggers, and so forth.`

So based in this idea, add a customized handler to your logger, and send to the server only `SEVERE` records:

```
  // This code is almost taken from the SimpleRemoteLogHandler.java because
  // it is a final class and we cannot extend it.
  logger.addHandler(new RemoteLogHandlerBase() {

    private AsyncCallback<String> callback = new AsyncCallback<String>() {
      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        wireLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Remote logging failed: ", caught);
      }
      public void onSuccess(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
          wireLogger.severe("Remote logging failed: " + result);
        } else {
          wireLogger.finest("Remote logging message acknowledged");
        }
      }
    };

    private RemoteLoggingServiceAsync service = (RemoteLoggingServiceAsync) GWT.create(RemoteLoggingService.class);

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
      if (record.getLevel() == Level.SEVERE) {
        if (isLoggable(record)) {
          service.logOnServer(record, callback);
        }
      }
    }

  });
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks @Manolo (+1) - quick question: is `RemoteLogHandlerBase` the one packaged in `gwt-user.jar`, or the one packaged in `gwt-servlet.jar`? Thanks again!

Comment: Actually they are the same class, many times gwt-servlet and get-user package have the same classes. I think once gwt were mavenized we would have more artifacts and each one with a set of classes which are not repeated in other modules.